# How can i make in the inspector options for each gameobject in the array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpinObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool slowDown = false;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float slowdownMax;
    public float slowdownMin;
    public GameObject[] objectsToRotate;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Length; i++)
        {
            if (rotationSpeed > slowdownMax)
                slowDown = true;
            else if (rotationSpeed < slowdownMin)
                slowDown = false;

            rotationSpeed = (slowDown) ? rotationSpeed - 0.1f : rotationSpeed + 0.1f;
            objectsToRotate[i].transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

I have array of game objects: GameObject[]
I want in the inspector to have options for each GameObject so when i change the options it will effect to gameobject and not all the gameobjects.

Each time i will add a new gmaeobject i want to have options for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a class or a simple struct I guess :

```
[System.Serializable]
public struct SpinableObject
{
    public Transform t ;
    public float rotationSpeed ;
    public float minSpeed ;
    public float maxSpeed ;
    public float speedRate;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool slowDown ;
}

public class SpinObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool slowDown = false;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float slowdownMax;
    public float slowdownMin;
    public GameObject[] objectsToRotate;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Length; i++)
        {
            SpinableObject spinableObject = objectsToRotate[i]

            if (spinableObject.rotationSpeed > spinableObject.maxSpeed )
                spinableObject.slowDown = true;
            else if (spinableObject.rotationSpeed < spinableObject.minSpeed )
                spinableObject.slowDown = false;

            spinableObject.rotationSpeed = (spinableObject.slowDown) ? spinableObject.rotationSpeed - 0.1f : spinableObject.rotationSpeed + 0.1f;
            spinableObject.t.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * spinableObject.rotationSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know which options you want to use, I did a little to much maybe. But if you want to use that much options, I would use a class with its own function to manage the rotation and another one to indicate whether the object should accelerate or decelerate.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SpinableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform t ;
    [SerializeField]
    private float rotationSpeed ;
    [SerializeField]
    private float minSpeed ;
    [SerializeField]
    private float maxSpeed ;
    [SerializeField]
    private float speedRate;
    private bool slowDown ;

    public void Rotate()
    {
        if (rotationSpeed > maxSpeed )
            slowDown = true;
        else if (rotationSpeed < minSpeed )
           slowDown = false;

        rotationSpeed = (slowDown) ? rotationSpeed - 0.1f : rotationSpeed + 0.1f;
        t.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    }
}

public class SpinObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool slowDown = false;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float slowdownMax;
    public float slowdownMin;
    public SpinableObject[] objectsToRotate;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Length; i++)
        {
            objectsToRotate[i].Rotate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could show me example of how to do it with the class/es please ? And about this solution i'm getting error on: SpinableObject spinableObject = objectsToRotate[i]; The error is on: objectsToRotate[i] Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'SpinableObject'

Comment: Ok i saw your edit now. Now i'm getting error on the line: objectsToRotate[i].Rotate(); 'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'Rotate' and no extension method 'Rotate' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I made an error when declaring the `objectsToRotate`, check my updated answer : `public SpinableObject[] objectsToRotate;` instead of `public GameObject[] objectsToRotate;`

Comment: Now it's working. I have another question please. Is it a good thing to put a loop(FOR) inside the Update ? (as the function is called every frame and the for loop would be activated every frame lowering the fps drastically). Maybe there should be some IF there or something else ?

Comment: Don't worry, a simple for loop won't make your FPS drop. Except if you have thousand objects in your array.